# Update URL with value from input on click with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

I'm trying to get the value of an input to be captured and then to update part of the URL with that value, all by doing a simple on click with React, ES6 etc. Basically a simple search functionality

So my component looks something like this:

```
class SearchInput extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      query: ''
    }
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    const handleSearchURL = window.location('/search/'+this.state.query+'/some-action')
    this.setState({
      handleSearch: handleSearchURL
    })
  }

  queryChange = (evt) => {
    this.setState({query: evt.target.value})
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSearch, placeholder } = this.props
    return (
      <form>
        <input id="site-search" type="search" placeholder={placeholder} value={this.state.query} />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" onClick={this.handleSearch} />
      </form>
    )
  }
}
```

but this just gives me a lot of errors and it seems to don't like window.location. What's the best way to achieve this? I'm using react-router so I'm also happy if there is a better way with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `browserHistory.push` or `this.context.router.push`. also componentDidMount is a lifeCycle function and doesnt require binding and is executed just once. You also need a handleSearch function and a `onChange` event on input query change

```js
class SearchInput extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      query: ''
    }
  }
  static contextTypes = {
       router: React.PropTypes.object
   }
  
  handleSearch = () => {
         this.context.router.push(`'/search/${this.state.query}/some-action'`);
  }
  queryChange = (evt) => {
    this.setState({query: evt.target.value})
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSearch, placeholder } = this.props
    return (
      <form>
        <input id="site-search" type="search" placeholder={placeholder} value={this.state.query} onChange={this.queryChange} />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" onClick={this.handleSearch} />
      </form>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesnt' seem to work, I get "can't read property push of undefined" in the console when I submit

Comment: static contextTypes = {
    router: React.PropTypes.object
  } updated the answer check

Answer (score 2):

You can use `"browserHistory"` from `'react-router'` and then push new url to here like this:

```
browserHistory.push('/search/{this.state.query}/some-action')
```

Comment: not present in v4 https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5263

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me with react-hooks and `react-router v5`

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

 const history = useHistory();

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    history.push(`/search/${input}`);
  };
```

see https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks

Answer (score 0):

function updateQueryStringParam(key, value, location) {
  const urlQueryString = location.search;
  const newParam = `${key}=${value}`;
  let params = `?${newParam}`;

// If the "search" string exists, then build params from it
  if (urlQueryString) {
    const updateRegex = new RegExp(`([?&])${key}[^&]*`);
    const removeRegex = new RegExp(`([?&])${key}=[^&;]+[&;]?`);

```
if (typeof value === 'undefined' || value == null || value === '') {
  // Remove param if value is empty
  params = urlQueryString.replace(removeRegex, '$1');
  params = params.replace(/[&;]$/, '');
} else if (urlQueryString.match(updateRegex) !== null) {
  // If param exists already, update it
  params = urlQueryString.replace(updateRegex, `$1${newParam}`);
} else {
  // Otherwise, add it to end of query string
  params = `${urlQueryString}&${newParam}`;
}
```

}

// no parameter was set so we don't need the question mark
  return (params = params === '?' ? '' : params);
}

const url = updateQueryStringParam('filter', inputValue, this.props.location);

this.props.history.push(url);